# Can multiple ngrams be used in the same classifier?

Tags: nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis, n-gram

I'm new to NLP and have a very simple question I expected to be asked a lot, but honestly couldn't find anywhere: can multiple types of ngrams be used within the same classifier (e.g. unigrams + bigrams)?

I have tried doing so, and, for Naive Bayes, at least, it gives me a higher accuracy than bigrams only (though lower than unigrams), but I am not sure whether it is a legitimate practice at all. One concern that I have is that there is potential for multicollinearity, if that's even an applicable term, i.e. both 'luck' and 'good luck' are near the top of the most informative features list.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "yes". The longer answer is, you can use anything you want as training features. But I suspect you are using the raw unigrams and bigrams as your features. If bigrams by themselves are less useful than unigrams, you clearly do not have enough training data for your application to make useful inferences from them. Add some higher-level features (e.g., a bigram of the POS tags) that have fewer possibilities and are therefore easier to generalize.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to implement something like POS tags if I get have the time (the deadline for the project is not so distant). You are right, by the way, my training data consists of barely 600 messages (often quite lengthy Kickstarter comments, though, not tweets, which hopefully redeems the minuscule training set size). On a related note, and to not ask a separate question, can such a small data set and accuracy ~68-70% (I have 3 classes) be considered acceptable if sentiment analysis is an auxiliary tool to more in-depth manual analysis of the comments?

Comment: Long messages or not, if each message is evaluated as a whole you have 600 data points. So avoid overtraining, e.g., bigrams. Acceptable accuracy depends on your goals, and (for a project) on the current state of the art.

Comment: Thanks once again :) I use SA to get a bird's eye view of dynamics in the discussion of various Kickstarter projects, so I think ~68% accuracy should be sufficient, given that some papers on movie review SA present even something like 64% accuracy as a respectable result.

Comment: One more random tip: Try it once with the stopwords left in. As I recall  "what a" is a marker of strong emotion, both positive and negative. You'll miss it if you remove "a" from the input. But I've no idea if this will raise or lower performance over all.

Comment: If Python is a go you can use TFIDFVECTORIZER to do it automatically for you by setting ngram_range to (1, 2) http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html

Comment: I believe the OP already knows how to do it, and has done so. The question asks whether it is a good idea.